# Recharts custom dot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, jsx, recharts

I have an `StackedAreaChart` and after I show areas on graph I want to add a custom dot.

Currently my code look like this but I want to draw a dot depend on `XAxis` and `YAxis` data. Does exist any way to pass `x` and `y` coordinates to a `CustomizedDot` class?

```
import React from 'react';
import { AreaChart, Area, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Label, Dot } from 'recharts';

const data = [
    { name: 142, underweight: 36.3, normal: 11.3, overweight: 6.8, obese: 56.7 },
    { name: 196, underweight: 70.3, normal: 22.7, overweight: 15.9, obese: 2.2 },
];

class CustomizedDot extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { cx, cy } = this.props;

        return (
            <circle cx={160} cy={50} r={25} stroke="black" strokeWidth={3} fill="red" />
        );
    }
};

class BMIGraph extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Index telesne mase za odrasle</h2>
                <AreaChart width={600} height={400} data={data} margin={{ top: 10, right: 30, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
                    <XAxis dataKey="name">
                        <Label value="Višina (cm)" offset={0} position="insideBottom" />
                    </XAxis>
                    <YAxis>
                        <Label value="Teža (kg)" angle={-90} position="insideLeft" textAnchor="middle" />
                    </YAxis>
                    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                    {/* <Tooltip /> */}
                    <CustomizedDot />
                    <Area type='monotone' dataKey='underweight' stackId="1" stroke='#8884d8' fill='#7d7dff' animationDuration={3500} name="Podhranjenost" dot={<CustomizedDot />} />
                    <Area type='monotone' dataKey='normal' stackId="1" stroke='#82ca9d' fill='#7dff7d' animationDuration={3500} name="Normalna teža" />
                    <Area type='monotone' dataKey='overweight' stackId="1" stroke='#ffc658' fill='#ffff7d' animationDuration={3500} name="Prekomerna teža" />
                    <Area type='monotone' dataKey='obese' stackId="1" stroke='#ffc658' fill='#ff7d7d' animationDuration={3500} name="Debelost" />
                </AreaChart>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default BMIGraph;
```

[The result of the current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKiJZ.png)

Answer (score 17):

You no need to pass X and Y axis data.

By using

```
const { cx, cy } = this.props;
```

`cx & cy` holds x, y position you required.

Try this in your `CustomizedDot` class

```
 class CustomizedDot extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { cx, cy } = this.props;

        return (
            <circle cx={cx - 10} cy={cy - 10} r={25} stroke="black" strokeWidth={3} fill="red" />
        );
    }
  };
```

Comment: @pol-albacar-fernandez Your edit comment is useful, but should be added as a comment here, to leave the answer as intended by its author.

Edit comment was: “Using <circle> element you can remove the "-10" in cx={cx-10} and cy={cy-10}. This will center your circle exactly at the original dot position.”

Comment: Where does the <circle /> element come from?

Answer (score 3):

For customized dots.
this.props already contains:
cx: Number,
cy: Number,
stroke: String,
payload: Object,
value: Number

cx and cy are the coordinates you are after, and if you are interested in the data as well, this.props.payload is probably the one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as above, just using typescript and as a functional component:

```
import React from 'react';

export const CustomScatterDot: React.FC<{ cx: number, cy: number }> = ({ cx, cy }) => {
  return (
    <circle
        cx={cx - 10}
        cy={cy - 10}
        r={4}
        stroke='black'
        style={{opacity: "0.9"}}
        strokeWidth={2}
        fill={"green"} />
  );
};
```